# VBA Run-time error '-2147024713' (800700b7) on WinHttpRequest

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replay a http request that I am copying from Chrome browser inspection.

When I recreate the request in VBA Excel there is a line that is causing the following error:

[image]

There are several headers in my request, but the error goes away when I remove this line:

```
req.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

The full request looks like:

```
Sub httpTest()

Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.Open "POST", "https://contoso.com/wft/bridge/gui/gen/rest/1.0/getData?endDate=2021-05-28+00:00:00.000&genieId=4", False
req.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
req.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Mobile Safari/537.36"
req.SetProxy 2, "webproxy.contoso.com:1234"
req.SetCredentials "user", "secret", 0

req.SetRequestHeader "accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
req.SetRequestHeader "accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
req.SetRequestHeader "accept-language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
req.SetRequestHeader "content-length", "9"
req.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
req.SetRequestHeader "cookie", "USER=QkS8fIs; JSESSIONID=h6hYe-d90995a0a398"
req.SetRequestHeader "csrf_tok", "OVSW-OG9M"
req.SetRequestHeader "origin", "https://contoso.com"
req.SetRequestHeader "referer", "https://contoso.com/static/applications/navigator/html5/di/gnies/index.html?version=8.1.6.4999&userLocale=en_US&widgetId=649"
req.SetRequestHeader "sec-fetch-mode", "cors"
req.SetRequestHeader "sec-fetch-site", "same-origin"

req.Send ("*abcd12")

End Sub
```

How to fix the error?

**UPDATE**

The error comes back if I try to add the user-agent header:

```
req.SetRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: On what line does this error occur?

Comment: You're setting content-type twice: I think you can only set any specific header once.

Comment: That seems to be it. Thanks. Good spotting.